# Leaf indices for GradientBoostingClassifier in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn

Is there any way to get the leaf indices for the `GradientBoostingClassifier` in scikit-learn as you can for the `RandomForestClassifier` with its [`apply(X)` method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.apply)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get call the `apply` method on each `estimator`, I think in the current release you have to call `gbrt.estimators[i].tree_.apply(X)`, which will simplify to `gbrt.estimators[i].apply(X)` in the next release iirc.